# Is the character group of a finite group its "dual"?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, duality-theorems

We know that for a (finite-dimensional) vector space over some fixed field $k$, we may construct its dual as the set of all its linear functionals. Now for a given (finite) group $G$, we may construct its set of all Dirichlet characters $\hat{G}$ and $\hat{G}$ forms a group. Now,  does $\hat{G}$ act as some sort of a dual of $G$, similar of some sort to the dual construction of a vector space? Also, what information do $\hat{G}$ tell about $G$? Are they isomorphic if $G$ is finite as in the case of finite-dimensional vector spaces? Thanks.

Comment: So by $\widehat{G}$ you mean the set of group homomorphisms $G \rightarrow k^\times$, where $k^\times = k \setminus \{ 0 \}$ is the multiplicative group of the field? First thing here is that $\widehat{G}$ is always abelian, so in general it is not isomorphic to $G$. If $G$ is finite, even the order will usually be different: e.g. if $G$ is non-abelian simple, then $\widehat{G}$ is trivial. This character group is more useful when you work with an abelian group $G$, see e.g. Pontryagin duality

Comment: Yes that what I meant about $\widehat{G}$. Thanks for the comment @spin. I will now look at Pontryagin duality.

Comment: Homomorphisms $G\to k^{\times}$ are just one-dimensional irreducible representations. The set of all (isomorphism classes of) irreducible representations of a finite group is in some sense dual to the set of all conjugacy classes. See [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/102894/16931) (you can ignore the Hopf stuff). Another generalization(ish) of Pontryagin duality is seen in Tannaka-Krein duality.